# Is the following statement true: $F_n\leq p\leq F_{n+2}$

Tags: prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

Let be $n\in\{2,3,\ldots\}$ Is the following statement true:

There exists a prime number so that $F_n\leq p\leq F_{n+2}$ while $F_n$ is a Fibonacci number.

Comment: See [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate).

Comment: Actually, we find $p$ with $F_n\le p\le F_{\color{red}{n+1}}$ except at the very beginning. This follows from a "slight" improvement over Bertrand. On the Wikipedia page referenced by Wojuwu, we find a result by Jitsuro Nagura: There is a prime between $n$ and $(1+\frac15)n$ for $n\ge 25$. As $1+\frac15<\frac{F_{k+1}}{F_k}\approx \frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$, we are left with checking only a few initial cases ...